# Slideshow using Prototype and Scriptaculous

Tags: prototypejs, slideshow, scriptaculous

I wrote my first scriptaculous script to create a slideshow between some div element :

```
    var SlideShow = Class.create({
    initialize:function(element, delayStart){
        this.element = element;
        this.delayStart = delayStart;


        this.slides = this.element.childElements();

        this.numberOfSlides = this.slides.size();

        this.numberActiveSlide = 1;

        this.start_slideshow();
    },

    start_slideshow: function() 
    {
        this.switch_slides.delay(this.delayStart);
    },

    switch_slides: function() 
    {
        this.slides[this.numberActiveSlide].fade();

        if (this.numberActiveSlide == this.numberOfSlides) { this.numberActiveSlide = 1; } else { this.numberActiveSlide = this.numberActiveSlide + 1; }

        Effect.Appear.delay(this.slides[this.numberActiveSlide], 850);

        this.switch_slides.delay(this.delay + 850);
    }


});

document.observe("dom:loaded", function(){
var slideshows = $$('div.slideshow');
slideshows.each(
    function(slideshow) {
        s = new SlideShow(slideshow, 2);
    });
});
```

But I always get this error and It's been hours I can't figure it out where my problem is!

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating this.slides[this.numberActiveSlide]);

Thanks you !

Nick

Comment: That error refers to the Object Instance and the `slides` property of that object. The slides property is looking for all the child elements  and there might not be any - can you edit your question and post your HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

99% sure it's a context issue. Make sure you [bind](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/bind/) your function calls so that `this` is retained throughout your code.

Debug what `this` is in `switch_slides`: it should be the same thing as `this` in `start_slideshow`. If it's not, bind your call to `switch_slides` to your instance:

```
start_slideshow: function() 
{
    this.switch_slides.bind(this).delay(this.delayStart);
},
```

You'll probably have to do the same in `switch_slides` where it calls itself.